# CryptoJS not decrypting if wrapped in a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptojs

I am experiencing an issue that is blowing my mind. I have two equal pieces of code, with the only difference that I wrapped a call (that I will use often in my class) inside a function in one of them, while in the other is explicit. Well, the one piece works, while the other does not.

This works fine:

```js
public testSymmetricEncryption(): void {
        const original = 'Understanding at the alpha quadrant that is when conscious klingons yell.';
        const password = 'myPassword';
        const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(original, password).toString();
        const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        console.log('Test symmetric encryption', {original, password, encrypted, decrypted});
    }
```

While this other does not work (no decrypted value give, i.e. `''`), and sometimes even an `Error: Malformed UTF-8 data` exception:

```js
public testSymmetricEncryption(): void {
        const original = 'Understanding at the alpha quadrant that is when conscious klingons yell.';
        const password = 'myPassword';
        const encrypted = this.encryptSymmetric(original, original);
        const decrypted = this.decryptSymmetric(encrypted, password);

        console.log('Test symmetric encryption', {original, password, encrypted, decrypted});
}

    public encryptSymmetric(value: string, password: string) {
        return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, password).toString();
}

    public decryptSymmetric(encrypted: string, password: string) {
        return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Anybody has an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a typo here. Instead of `const encrypted = this.encryptSymmetric(original, original);`, I think it should be `const encrypted = this.encryptSymmetric(original, password);`

Comment: I have checked a thousand times and didn't see it. That was it. Thanks god, my life makes sense again. I have to  delete  this  question now, I  guess.